# Simplify expression with function with symmetric arguments

Tags: pattern-matching

I have the following expression

$$ \frac{1}{2}\partial_\nu\partial_\xi h^{\nu\xi}-\frac{1}{2}\partial_\nu\partial_\xi h^{\xi\nu}+ \partial_\xi\partial_\nu h^{\xi\nu}- \frac{1}{2}\partial^\nu\partial_\nu h- \frac{1}{2}\partial^\xi\partial_\xi h ~~~(*)$$

where $h_{\mu\nu}=h_{\nu\mu}$ is symmetric and we use the summation convention, i.e., indices that appear twice are summed over. We use the notation $\partial_\nu=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\nu}$ to denote the derivative with respect to the $\nu$s component of the $x$ vector. Of course derivatives commute, i.e., $\partial_\nu\partial_\mu=\partial_\mu\partial_\nu$. One sees directly that the expression above simplifies to:

$$ \partial_\xi\partial_\nu h^{\xi\nu}-\partial^\nu\partial_\nu h$$

My question is how I can make Mathematica to do this step automatically? The expression in $(*)$ in Mathematica is:

```
1/2 ddh[nu, xi, nu, xi] - 1/2 ddh[nu, xi, xi, nu] + 
ddh[xi, nu, xi, nu] - 1/2 ddht[nu, nu] - 1/2 ddht[xi, xi]
```

I think I have to use some pattern functions but I don't see how I would use them in my case to get the desired simplification?

Comment: Why is the last term in the simplified (LateX) output positive? Could you please also include the output in Mathematica format?

Comment: It was a typo. It's corrected now.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand what you mean but I did include the Mathematica code, no? You should be able to copy and past it into your Mathematica notebook

Comment: `- 1/2 ddht[nu, nu] - 1/2 ddht[xi, xi]`  converts to `-ddht[nu, nu] `?

Comment: Yes. I want mathematica to do this step automatically. It should recognize that these two terms are the same

Comment: You can see that they are the same because what they mean is $-\sum_\nu \frac{1}{2}\partial_\nu \partial^\nu h-\sum_\xi \frac{1}{2}\partial_\xi \partial^\xi h$. I just left out the sum in the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the following; but you can also define function arguments using the `OrderlessPatternSequence`. I cannot determine, how it will play out for the rest of your computation without further context.

```
expr = 1/2 ddh[nu, xi, nu, xi] - 1/2 ddh[nu, xi, xi, nu] + 
  ddh[xi, nu, xi, nu] - 1/2 ddht[nu, nu] - 1/2 ddht[xi, xi]

expr /. {ddh[OrderlessPatternSequence[nu, xi], 
    OrderlessPatternSequence[nu, xi]] :>  ddh[nu, xi, nu, xi], 
  ddht[a_, a_] :> ddht[nu, nu]}
```

> ddh[nu, xi, nu, xi] - ddht[nu, nu]